# Jquery, change field value based on conditions - NaN

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have different results when:

1. the fields values change.
2. the select_field change

But the `result_field` get the result `NaN`

This is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        var $quant = $('#deriva_move_quantidade');
        var $price = $('#deriva_move_valor');
        var $price_2 = $('#deriva_move_valor_recompra');
        var $result_field = $('#deriva_move_resultado')
        
        var $result = $quant * $price; 
        var $result_2 = $result - $quant * $price_2
        var $result_3 = 0
        
        $('#select_field').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value == '1' || this.value == '3' )
          {
            $result_field.val($result)
          }
          else if ( this.value == '2' )
          {
            $result_field.val($result_2)
          }
          else (this.value == '4')
          {
            $result_field.val($result_3)  
          }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_field">
      <option selected="selected" value="1">Aberta</option>
      <option value="2">Exercicio</option>
      <option value="3">Po</option>
      <option value="4">Recompra</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" value="0.32" id="deriva_move_valor">
    <input type="number" value="100" id="deriva_move_quantidade">
    <input type="text" id="deriva_move_valor_recompra">
    <input type="text" value="32.0" id="deriva_move_resultado">
```

Trying the solution with answers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $result_field = $('#deriva_move_resultado');
    let $quant = parseInt($('#deriva_move_quantidade').val());
    let $price = parseFloat($('#deriva_move_valor').val());
    let $price_2 = parseFloat($('#deriva_move_valor_recompra').val());
    let $result = $quant * $price; 
    let $result_2 = $result - $quant * $price_2;
    let $result_3 = 0
    
    $('#select_field').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1' || this.value == '3' )
      {
        $result_field.val($result)
      }
      else if ( this.value == '2' )
      {
        $result_field.val($result_2)
      }
      else (this.value == '4')
      {
        $result_field.val($result_3)  
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="deriva_move[estado_id]" id="select_field">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Aberta</option>
  <option value="2">Exercicio</option>
  <option value="3">Po</option>
  <option value="4">Recompra</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="0.32" name="deriva_move[valor]" id="deriva_move_valor">
<input type="number" name="deriva_move[quantidade]" id="deriva_move_quantidade">
<input type="text" name="deriva_move[valor_recompra]" id="deriva_move_valor_recompra">
<input type="text" name="deriva_move[resultado]" id="deriva_move_resultado">
<script>
```

Comment: I am assuming that this line `var $result_2 = $resultado - $quantidade * $valor_recompra` which contains undefined elements is actually this `var $result_2 = $result - $quant * $price_2`.

Comment: Also adding some `HTML` would be great since we do not know for sure that `#deriva_move_resultado` is an `input` element. Otherwise `.val()` should not be used.

Comment: @Peter Darmis, just added the html

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in these lines of code:

```
var $quant = $('#deriva_move_quantidade');
var $price = $('#deriva_move_valor');
var $price_2 = $('#deriva_move_valor_recompra');
...
```

By using `$('#deriva_move_quantidade')` you are storing a reference to the JQuery function with the selector `#deriva_move_quantidade` in `$quant` (and so on for the other variables).

I suspect that you actually want the values from these which can be obtained using `val()`:

```
var $quant = $('#deriva_move_quantidade').val();
var $price = $('#deriva_move_valor').val();
var $price_2 = $('#deriva_move_valor_recompra').val();
...
```

**Update following OP comment**

The `$result_field` variable should not use `.val()` because of the way it is used later (i.e. `$result_field.val($result)`).  So the declaration lines of could should be:

```
var $quant = $('#deriva_move_quantidade').val();
var $price = $('#deriva_move_valor').val();
var $price_2 = $('#deriva_move_valor_recompra').val();
var $result_field = $('#deriva_move_resultado'); // Don't add .val()!

var $resul = $quant * $price; 
...
```

Comment: hi @Martin, thanks. I just added .val(), but now the result_field don't change the value, am i missing something?

Comment: @DiogoWernik Don't add `.val()` to the result field: `var $result_field = $('#deriva_move_resultado');`

Comment: Yes @Martin, i didn't add, but the mathematic operation doesn't work yet, when i change de select field, i just strip the decimal.

Comment: @DiogoWernik That could be a casting issue to do with `int`s vs `float`s.  You may need to convert the variables to the appropriate datatypes using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` depending upon your requirement

Comment: Hi @Martin, i just added the html

Answer (score 1):

The way you are assigning your first three variables is not correct, you need to get the value of your three jquery selectors, you should define them as follow

```
var $quant = $('#deriva_move_quantidade').val();
var $price = $('#deriva_move_valor').val();
var $price_2 = $('#deriva_move_valor_recompra').val();
```

I would recommend also that you change the way you are naming them since naming the variable as you do can lead to a miss understanding of their intention, because when prefixing a variable name by **$**, it comes in mind that it is a reference to a jquery selector.
So to keep your code cleaner and respectfull to the javascript naming standards

```
var quant = $('#deriva_move_quantidade').val();
var price = $('#deriva_move_valor').val();
var price_2 = $('#deriva_move_valor_recompra').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code as in the following example.

I am assuming that this line `var $result_2 = $resultado - $quantidade * $valor_recompra` which contains undefined elements is actually `this var $result_2 = $result - $quant * $price_2`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    const $result_field = $('#deriva_move_resultado');
    let $quant = parseInt($('#deriva_move_quantidade').val());
    let $price = parseFloat($('#deriva_move_valor').val());
    let $price_2 = parseFloat($('#deriva_move_valor_recompra').val());
    let $result = $quant * $price; 
    let $result_2 = $result - $quant * $price_2;
    let $result_3 = 0
    
    $('#select_field').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1' || this.value == '3' )
      {
        $result_field.val($result)
      }
      else if ( this.value == '2' )
      {
        $result_field.val($result_2)
      }
      else (this.value == '4')
      {
        $result_field.val($result_3)  
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: @thanks peter, i just added the html code also, to make it easier to understand the code, it is almost there, i will check your solution.